# how to callback didSelectRowAtIndexPath while using selectRowAtIndexPath by coding

Tags: ios

I use

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

to scroll a table to a cell, and I want to change the text color in the cell.
But,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

all can not be callback.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a deprecated attribute:

cell.selectedTextColor

not very good, but works.

Comment: This is almost definitely going to cause you problems in a year or two when Apple gets around to removing that property. You should try to find a non-deprecated way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Call it yourself...

```
[tableView.delegate tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:index];
```